# Can I use one servlet to receive xmpp messages, and another to send them in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

Does the required servlet URL mapping (/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/) for the xmpp service restrict me to using only that servlet for both sending and receiving xmpp messages?

My application receives messages, adds them to an 'inQueue' for processing, and once processed, the results are added to an 'outQueue'. Ideally I'd like the worker servlet assigned to the outQueue to send the response.

I am using push queues and the servlets are obviously invoked by an HTTP POST request...

When I try to use the xmpp service to send the message from my outQueue worker ( which is obviously not mapped to /_ah/xmpp/message/chat/ ), it expectedly does nothing.

In the servlet mapped to /_ah/xmpp/message/chat/:

```
//Generate a Memcache key 
String key = generateMemcacheKey(message);

//Serialize the message as xml using getStanza (for now, just put in the senderJID as string)
String senderJIDString = message.getFromJid().getId();

//Cache the message in Memcache
cache.put(key, senderJIDString);

//Enqueue a task for the message
private Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("inQueue");
queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/xmppParser").param("memcacheKey", key));
```

In xmppParser servlet doPost method:

```
//Extract message from memcache
String key = req.getParameter("memcacheKey");
String recipientJIDString = (String)cache.get(key);

//Todo Detect language

//Todo Parse Message into an Imperative accordingly (For now, just reply hello)

//Todo Handle Session status

//Put Imperative into memcache (For now, just put recipientID in)
cache.put(key, recipientJIDString);

//Enqueue appropriately
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("outQueue");
queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/responseServlet").param("memcacheKey", key
));
```

Now I would like this responseServlet to send the reply:

```
//Get a handler on the memcache
MemcacheService cache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();

//Extract the key to the response from the request
String key = req.getParameter("memcacheKey");

//Extract the message from the memcache ( For now it's just the JID of the sender)
String recipientJIDString = (String)cache.get(key);

//Parse it into a message (For now just make a simple "I hear you" message)
JID recipientJID = new JID(recipientJIDString);
Message response = new MessageBuilder()
    .withMessageType(MessageType.NORMAL)
    .withRecipientJids(recipientJID)
    .withBody("I hear you")
    .build();

//Send the message
XMPPService xmpp = XMPPServiceFactory.getXMPPService();
xmpp.sendMessage(response);
```

The servlet mappings are all kosher, and the xmpp service is unable to send the message. It raises a null pointer exception, but the memcache viewer confirms the recipientJID is kosher as well... I'm guessing only the servlet mapped to /_ah/xmpp/message/chat/ is able to send messages, or am I wrong?

I am forced to test on the live site itself as XMPP does not seem to be supported by the development server, adding the possibility of my having overlooked some production environment configuration...

Much obliged!

ram

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some code (that receives/sends messages) and point out what part does not work.

Comment: I get the NPE at xmpp.sendMessage(response) - but to clarify, can you confirm or deny that two different servlets in one webapp may service xmpp? One to receive messages and one to send? I currently have the app working with the same servlet both sending and receiving xmpp.